# How to prevent parent being choosen in wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: categories

I have a grand-parent-category with several parent-category. Each groundchild means a specific method to process later. Parents should not be selected, it merely means to group the children together.

I use `wp_dropdown_categories` with `child_of` to show the dropdown form. The parents shows up as a choice which can course confusing for users.

```
wp_dropdown_categories('child_of'=>$ground_parent_id);
```

If I add `exclude = $parent_ids`, the whole dropdown list gone.

```
wp_dropdown_categories('child_of'=>$groun_parent_id,'exclude'=>$parent_ids );
```

I can throw error message or process to a default value if a user choosed a parent, but this is a way to frustrat my users. Is there any other way to make a dropdown without parent?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest solution for you , providing you do not have 200 categories, is to use the exclude AND include parameters together . Alternatively , you can construct your own list with get_categories. or use the exclude_tree .